# How can I get oauth_access_token for facebook-sdk

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to code that post facebook. So I decided to use python-sdk (https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk).
Then I hit a problem.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
```

How can I get this "`oauth_access_token`"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an authorization flow. Access tokens are the keys used after getting proper authorization.

> An access token is an opaque string that identifies a user, app, or
>   page and can be used by the app to make graph API calls. Access tokens
>   are obtained via a number of methods, each of which are covered later
>   in this document. The token includes information about when the token
>   will expire and which app generated the token. Because of privacy
>   checks, the majority of API calls on Facebook need to include an
>   access token.

There are various ways to obtain an access token all explained in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

For testing, one must create an app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps and can be issued an access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token

Comment: Tanks.I could get access_token to access the following page. this returned string is acces_token ,isn't this? https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=MY_APP_ID
&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET
&grant_type=client_credentials

Comment: @EriIsurugi That's an app access token. You need a **user** access token. Please read the information given above on various ways to get one.

Comment: thanks to your polite teaching, I managed to get user access token. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Here is a way to get the user access token :

```
instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=request.user, provider='facebook')
token = instance.tokens
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token['access_token'])
```

Maybe you've already figured this out, just in case somebody else is looking for it

Comment: This is specific to django, and is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Oh yes it is, sorry I didn't see! Do I need to remove my answer ? Or just let it here, somebody using django might find it useful